# How to check for duplicates in mysql table over multiple columns

Tags: mysql, sql, search, duplicates

I have a table of baseball players(all 1000 or so), with fields:

```
mysql> describe person;
+-----------+-------------+------+-----+---------+----------------+
| Field     | Type        | Null | Key | Default | Extra          |
+-----------+-------------+------+-----+---------+----------------+
| id        | int(11)     | NO   | PRI | NULL    | auto_increment |
| firstname | varchar(30) | NO   |     | NULL    |                |
| lastname  | varchar(30) | NO   |     | NULL    |                |
+-----------+-------------+------+-----+---------+----------------+
```

But I think there are some players that have gotten added in twice. How can I go through and check for how many occurrences of a particular firstname, lastname combo?

Comment: Do what @RC said, then add a `(firstname,lastname)` unique key

Answer (score 63, accepted):

This provides the list of duplicates:

```
SELECT firstname, lastname, COUNT(*) 
FROM person 
GROUP BY firstname, lastname 
HAVING COUNT(*) > 1;
```

If you want to see the counts for every row remove the having clause:

```
SELECT firstname, lastname, COUNT(*) 
FROM person 
GROUP BY firstname, lastname;
```

Comment: Clearly the best answer possible.

Answer (score 4):

```
SELECT firstname, lastname, count(id) count
  FROM person
 WHERE firstname = ?
   AND lasttname = ?
 GROUP BY firstname, lastname
```

Comment: that only tells you _if_ a particular person is a duplicate, not _which_ persons are duplicated.

Comment: ah, yes, I see what you mean. I believe he meant _particular_ as in _"distinct"_, rather than _"specific"_.  I was similarly vague in my comment, where I did indeed mean _"specific"_ ! :)

Answer (score 2):

For a list sorted by decreasing value of the number of copies:

```
SELECT firstname, lastname, COUNT(*) AS n
  FROM person
 GROUP BY firstname, lastname
 ORDER BY n DESC
 HAVING n > 1
```

The `HAVING` clause is the key part - it's necessary to filter the results *after* the `GROUP BY` clause, since a `WHERE` clause filters out rows *before* they're grouped.

Answer (score 1):

To get id's of duplicate names as well as names do:

```
SELECT p1.id, p1.firstname, p1,lastname FROM person p1
INNER JOIN person p2 ON (p1.firstname = p2.firstname 
                         AND p1.lastname = p1.lastname 
                         AND p1.id <> p2.id);
```

Comment: @Alnitak, don't listen to what I say, listen to what I mean :-).

Answer (score 1):

If you simply want to erase all the duplicate, you could do a temporary table and fill it up with all you`re data except the duplicate and them re-update you`re primary table.

The query to select the data with duplicate would be this

```
 SELECT DISTINCT firstname, lastname FROM table
```

To get the complete list of data in you're table

```
SELECT firstname, lastname, COUNT(*) AS n
  FROM person
 GROUP BY firstname, lastname
 ORDER BY lastname DESC
 HAVING n > 1
```

With this last query you'll get a the list of data sorted by lastname Alphabeticly.

Answer (score 1):

To find duplicate records (ex: to find login name and password combination of duplicate records) in a table use the below query;

```
SELECT em.* FROM employee_master AS em JOIN 
 (SELECT emp.login, emp.password, COUNT(*) 
  FROM employee_master emp 
  WHERE emp.login != '' AND emp.password != '' 
  GROUP BY emp.login, emp.PASSWORD
  HAVING COUNT(*) > 1
 ) AS dl 
WHERE em.login =  dl.login AND em.password = dl.password;
```