# Trying to find duplicate values in TWO rows and TWO columns - SQL Server

Tags: sql, sql-server, select

Using SQL Server, I'm not a DBA but I can write some general SQL. Been pulling my hair out for about an hour now. Searching I've found several solutions but they all fail due to how GROUP BY works.

I have a table with two columns that I'm trying to check for duplicates:

- userid
- orderdate

I'm looking for rows that have BOTH `userid` and `orderdate` as duplicates. I want to display these rows.

If I use group by, I can't pull any other data, such as the order ID, because it's not in the group by clause.

Comment: Welcome to **SO**.. Add the following data in question : sample data, expected result and the query you have tried so far

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask

Comment: Learn how to ask question.  Without sample data, table structure, how do expect people to help you?

Comment: This might have already been answered here: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6454805/how-to-check-for-duplicates-in-mysql-table-over-multiple-columns

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You could use the grouped query in a subquery:

```
SELECT *
FROM   mytable a
WHERE  EXISTS (SELECT   userid, orderdate
               FROM     mytable b
               WHERE    a.userid = b.userid AND a.orderdate = b.orderdate
               GROUP BY userid, orderdate
               HAVING   COUNT(*) > 1)
```

Comment: How would this `HAVING   COUNT(*) = 0` give what OP wants?

Comment: @WEI_DBA I literally don't know what I was thinking... Edited and fixed

Comment: Mureinik you're my hero. This works perfectly. I've been able to modify it to add the info I need and bingo. Thank you - seriously.

Answer (score 1):

You can also use a windowed function:

```
; With CTE as 
    (Select *
    , count(*) over (partition by UserID, OrderDate) as DupRows
    from MyTable)

Select *
from CTE
where DupRows > 1
order by UserID, OrderDate
```

Comment: Thanks for your help !

Answer (score 0):

You can get the duplicates by using the groupby and having. Like so:

```
SELECT
    userid,orderdate, COUNT(*)
FROM
    yourTable
GROUP BY
    userid,orderdate
HAVING 
    COUNT(*) > 1
```

EDIT:

```
SELECT * FROM yourTable
WHERE CONCAT(userid,orderdate) IN
(
    SELECT
        CONCAT(userid,orderdate)
    FROM
        yourTable
    GROUP BY
        userid,orderdate
    HAVING 
        COUNT(*) > 1
)
```

Comment: Yes, this will give you the duplicates, but they also want all of the columns in the result set. Good start though.

Comment: Yeah thanks for this :) This is where I started but couldn't get the rest of the columns as @WEI_DBA mentioned

Answer (score 0):

```
SELECT * 
FROM myTable 
WHERE CAST(userid as Varchar) + '/' + CONVERT(varchar(10),orderdate,103) In 
(
    SELECT 
        CAST(userid as Varchar) + '/' + CONVERT(varchar(10),orderdate,103)
    FROM myTable
    GROUP BY userid , orderdate
    HAVING COUNT(*) > 1
);
```

Comment: While technically, this will get you the correct answer, the concatenation will kill performance if the data set is large. You would want to evaluate the two fields independently.

Comment: Thanks for your help !